# Can you compare data sets with percentages with the Chi Square test?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I’m confused about the Chi Square test.. Apparently you have to use it when comparing frequencies only, but what if both data sets are percentages? e.g. comparing the percentage of smokers in specific countries to the percentage of lung cancer incidents in those countries. Could I use the Chi Square test then, or would I have to convert the percentages of both data sets into frequencies?

Comment: frequencies can be given either as percentages, or as ratios; ultimately, the ratio is a percentage, i.e., 1/2 becomes the percentage value $50%$